# Table special Cellspacing

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `table` in which I don't want to set `padding` &/or `margin` on each `td` to apply some spacing between cells, First answer would be to use `CellSpacing` and/or `CellPadding` properties of `table` but when I use these properties they apply space on every side(i.e. on top, bottom, left and right) but I just want to apply space on Top and Bottom.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: That would be redundant, I have lots of tr and td in that table.

Comment: There's nothing like CellSpacingTop or anything similar. Using margin or padding is the way to go. And I don't get at all how it'd be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `padding` with `<td>` to have space on top and bottom in table cell.

To add spacing between rows of table, set `<tr>` as `block` element then you can use `margin` property on that.

Check the demo here http://codepen.io/pen/10248/2

**Edits:**

Updated to contain spacing between rows.

Comment: Padding will add space inside cell, but it will not add space between rows.

Comment: i have updated the code that adds spacing b/w rows. Please check out http://codepen.io/pen/10248/2

Comment: I checked the link you have given and margin for tr is working there. But trying the same on code is not working locally. I dont know why.:(

Comment: @Rain it's running totally fine locally. I cross checked there is no problem. screenshot:http://minus.com/m6N7gCI9T/

Comment: and i don't see a reason why it would not run locally.!!

Answer (score 0):

Use empty row for spacing

See the example below

```
 <table class="style1">
        <tr style="height: 20px;">
            <td>
                sfgefgfeg</td>
            <td>
                &sfgefgfeg;</td>
            <td>
                &sfgefgfeg;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 5px;" >
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 20px;">
            <td>
                &sfgefgfeg;</td>
            <td>
                &sfgefgfeg;</td>
            <td>
                &sfgefgfeg;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 20px;">
            <td>
                &sfgefgfeg;</td>
            <td>
                &sfgefgfeg;</td>
            <td>
                &sfgefgfeg;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here the row with height 5px is added for spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use border-top and border-bottom on the TD elements and make the colour of the border the same as the background colour of your page.

Answer (score 0):

you can simulate spacing by adding `border-bottom: 3px solid #fff` (change color as you need, same for top)

Answer (score 0):

The alternative ways to create spacing between cells (so that the spacing appears between borders, if cells have borders) is to use `cellspacing` attribute on a `table` element in HTML and to use the `border-spacing` property in CSS. The former suffers from the inflexibility mentioned in the question. The latter has limited browser support. You could use both, so that older browsers use the simple HTML spacing and newer browsers the CSS way.

The following example sets a vertical spacing (i.e., between rows) of 0.5em and a smaller, 0.1em, horizontal spacing (i.e., between columns).

```
table { border-spacing: 0.1em 0.3em; }
```

(The order deviates from the usual order in CSS property values: here horizontal comes first, then vertical, whereas e.g. in margin: 0.1em 0.3m an opposite order applies.)